# Terraform: How do I create an S3 bucket with objects in it which contain timestamp of when the code was executed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

Guys.

I am trying to create an S3 bucket with objects containing timestamp of when the code was executed. In other words, the code has to create an S3 bucket, create objects in the S3 bucket, and create a timestamp of when the code was executed in the objects. The objects must contain the timestamp.

My code goes thus:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_terraform_bucket" {
  bucket = "shaanu-bucket234589545"
  acl    = "private"


  provisioner "remote-exec" {
     inline = [
           " echo timestamp(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) > /home/shaanu/remote-exec/file12.txt 
            /home/shaanu/remote-exec/file22.txt" 
]

}

 connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ubuntu"
    host = "self.public_ip"
}



}
```

But I got this result:

```
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket: Creating...
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket: Provisioning with 'remote-exec'...
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   Host: self.public_ip
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   User: ubuntu
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   Password: false
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   Private key: false
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: false
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   Target Platform: unix
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec):   Target Platform: unix
aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...Error: remote-exec provisioner error
│
│   with aws_s3_bucket.my_terraform_bucket,
│   on remote-exec-provisioner.tf line 6, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_terraform_bucket":
│    6:   provisioner "remote-exec" {
│
│ timeout - last error: dial tcp: lookup self.public_ip on XXX.XXX.1.1:XX: no such host
```

I am certain I am not doing a couple of things right. Could someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried all kinds of variants, but have been quite unsuccessful with it. A few times, the bucket was created, but no files were created. How would you go about it please?

Comment: You have to show exactly what you tried, and what errors you got. New question could be made for these new trials.

Comment: I will do as suggested; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [aws_s3_bucket_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object) to upload files to your newly created object. `remote-exec` is not suited for that.

Comment: Thank you, Marcin. But how do I go about including the code for creating timestamp in the objects? That is the most challenging part to me.

Comment: @shaanu it's not clear what you mean. Maybe edit your question and try to explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, Marcin. What I am trying to do is create an AWS S3 bucket with a couple files. The content of the files should be the timestamp when the code was executed.

Comment: @shaanu look at the `content` parameter for `aws_s3_bucket_object`. You should use something like `content = timestamp()`.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB. I had tried it previously, but did not get the desired result.